# Magento 2 How to add DataTable script in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, grid

I need a custom Grid in **Magento2** admin panel, so i found data table code [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html). Please help me, how to add this data table code in my custom module.

Downloaded plugin files:

`Retailers/Catalog/view/adminhtml/web/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css` `Retailers/Catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js` `Retailers/Catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/jquery-1.12.3.js`

**Retailers/Catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_product.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Retailer Products</title>
    <css src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" src_type="url" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" src_type="url" />
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Retailers\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" name="company_block_adminhtml_index_test"  template="Retailers_Catalog::company_test.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**Retailers/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/company_test.phtml**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2011/04/25</td>
    <td>$320,800</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>2011/07/25</td>
    <td>$170,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>2009/01/12</td>
    <td>$86,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>2012/03/29</td>
    <td>$433,060</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Airi Satou</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>2008/11/28</td>
    <td>$162,700</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2012/12/02</td>
    <td>$372,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>2012/08/06</td>
    <td>$137,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>2010/10/14</td>
    <td>$327,900</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>2009/09/15</td>
    <td>$205,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>2008/12/13</td>
    <td>$103,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
    <td>Office Manager</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2008/12/19</td>
    <td>$90,560</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
    <td>Support Lead</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>2013/03/03</td>
    <td>$342,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>2008/10/16</td>
    <td>$470,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>2012/12/18</td>
    <td>$313,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>2010/03/17</td>
    <td>$385,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michael Silva</td>
    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>2012/11/27</td>
    <td>$198,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>2010/06/09</td>
    <td>$725,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gloria Little</td>
    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>2009/04/10</td>
    <td>$237,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>2012/10/13</td>
    <td>$132,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dai Rios</td>
    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>2012/09/26</td>
    <td>$217,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
    <td>Development Lead</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2011/09/03</td>
    <td>$345,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>2009/06/25</td>
    <td>$675,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>2011/12/12</td>
    <td>$106,450</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
    <td>Sidney</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>2010/09/20</td>
    <td>$85,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2009/10/09</td>
    <td>$1,200,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>2010/12/22</td>
    <td>$92,575</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>2010/11/14</td>
    <td>$357,650</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>2011/06/07</td>
    <td>$206,850</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Fiona Green</td>
    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>2010/03/11</td>
    <td>$850,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shou Itou</td>
    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>2011/08/14</td>
    <td>$163,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michelle House</td>
    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
    <td>Sidney</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>2011/06/02</td>
    <td>$95,400</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Suki Burks</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>2009/10/22</td>
    <td>$114,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
    <td>Technical Author</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/05/07</td>
    <td>$145,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
    <td>Team Leader</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>2008/10/26</td>
    <td>$235,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>2011/03/09</td>
    <td>$324,050</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unity Butler</td>
    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2009/12/09</td>
    <td>$85,675</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
    <td>Office Manager</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>2008/12/16</td>
    <td>$164,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
    <td>Secretary</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>2010/02/12</td>
    <td>$109,850</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
    <td>Financial Controller</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>2009/02/14</td>
    <td>$452,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
    <td>Office Manager</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>2008/12/11</td>
    <td>$136,200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
    <td>Director</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>2008/09/26</td>
    <td>$645,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
    <td>Support Engineer</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>2011/02/03</td>
    <td>$234,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>2011/05/03</td>
    <td>$163,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
    <td>Support Engineer</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>2009/08/19</td>
    <td>$139,575</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Thor Walton</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2013/08/11</td>
    <td>$98,540</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
    <td>Support Engineer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2009/07/07</td>
    <td>$87,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>2012/04/09</td>
    <td>$138,575</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>2010/01/04</td>
    <td>$125,250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
    <td>Software Engineer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>2012/06/01</td>
    <td>$115,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>2013/02/01</td>
    <td>$75,650</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>2011/12/06</td>
    <td>$145,600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>2011/03/21</td>
    <td>$356,250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lael Greer</td>
    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>2009/02/27</td>
    <td>$103,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2010/07/14</td>
    <td>$86,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shad Decker</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>2008/11/13</td>
    <td>$183,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>2011/06/27</td>
    <td>$183,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Donna Snider</td>
    <td>Customer Support</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/01/25</td>
    <td>$112,000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
require([
    "jquery"
], function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        } );
    });
});
</script>
```

Finally, it will show table only Grid not working(js file not loading).

Comment: can you specify more detail about your requirement, what you want.

Comment: Okey I will share my code

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: My Magento version is 2.1.7.
Please update your answer

Comment: @RajeshNagappan Any solutions about that?